# Print a div content with background color in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to print a div using jquery. (window.print()). The div has got background color. When I try to print, it just wont print the background color. Is there any way around.

In IE9 and above I have managed to convert it to an image uri using html2canvas, but this doesnt work on IE8.

If there is any way around please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Don't force your users into a situation where they have to (potentially, from their perspective) waste ink, or toner, printing out your page. By all means make it an option, but don't presume they'll want the background; unless the background is, for some reason, the image or content of your page. But if that's the case you may be doing it wrong.

Comment: David, that div that i am trying to print is a chart. It has got tables, spans, chart. So the information is required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect solution to this one but you could use `@media print` to add style for your print, then define the style you want for your `div`

[image]

`-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` are only for webkit broswers like chrome. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust

```js
function myFunction() {
  background: window.print();
}
```

```css
@media print {
  div {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}

div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>I'm the div and I should be red</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Daniel. However this                                                     
   "@media print {
  div {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}"   is already in place. It works on Chrome. I am looking for a solution that is compatible with IE8 if possible.

Comment: @Leo oh, only chrome and safari are supported, all other browser are not supported this `@media print` feature. Link ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust